# Invite users to your app via the Instagram API

Tags: instagram

Can I invite users like on Facebook? I have a website which has an Instagram login feature. If the user logs in with Instagram he sees his friends who he could invite to join my site.

Is there such feature available in the API and if so where can I find it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instagram API does not return email address of followers or a way to send message to followers, so you cannot do this. The best way to notify users is to post a photo and add a caption inviting your followers to the website. People who see this photo may visit your website.